# What is the difference between predict and svmclassify?

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I tried the following code

```
data =  [27    9   0
    11.6723281  28.93422177 0
    25  9   0
    23  8   0
    5.896096039 23.97745722 1
    21  6   0
    21.16823369 5.292058423 0
    4.242640687 13.43502884 1
    22  6   0];
    Attributes = data(:,1:2);
    Classes = data(:,3);
    train = [1 3 4 5 6 7];
    test = [2 8 9];
    %%# Train
   SVMModel = fitcsvm(Classes(train),Attributes(train,:))
   classOrder = SVMModel.ClassNames
   sv = SVMModel.SupportVectors;
   figure
   gscatter(train(:,1),train(:,2),Classes)
   hold on
   plot(train(:,1),train(:,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10)
   legend('good','bad','Support Vector')
   hold off
```

I tried both `predict` and `svmclassify`; but it returns an error. What is the basic difference between these two functions?

```
 [label,score] = predict(SVMModel,test);
 label           = svmclassify(SVMModel, test);
```

Comment: "It returns an error" - then use it how the documentation suggests and you'll see the outputs and the differences, or be less vague here! [`predict`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/predict.html): This predict command computes the K-step ahead output of an identified model. [`svmclassify`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmclassify.html):  classifies each row of the data in Sample, a matrix of data, using the information in a support vector machine classifier structure.

Comment: @Wolfie not necessarily true for the `predict`. See my answer; there's loads and loads of functions named `predict`, all doing something else based on whatever input system you feed it.

Comment: Ah lazy of me just copying the first docs result, but *slightly less* lazy perhaps than the OP who showed no evidence of even doing that ;) good one for the elaborated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's quite a big note on top of the [documentation page on `svmclassify`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/svmclassify.html):

> `svmclassify` will be removed in a future release. See [`fitcsvm`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html), [`ClassificationSVM`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm-class.html), and [`CompactClassificationSVM`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm-class.html) instead.

MATLAB is a bit vague in its naming of functions, as there's loads of functions named `predict`, using different schemes and algorithms. I suspect you'll want to use [the one for SVMs](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm.predict.html). This *should* return the same result as `svmclassify`, but I think that either something went wrong in determining which `predict` MATLAB decided to use, or that `predict` has a newer algorithm than the unsupported `svmclassify`, hence a different output may result.

The conclusion is that you should use the newest functions to be able to run your code in future releases and get the newest algorithms. MATLAB will choose the correct version of `predict` based on what kind of input structure you feed it.